# cabal install fails because missing C library

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, cabal, udev, hidapi

I want to install hemokit driver by the command `cabal install hemokit` command, but it's tells me that it fails when it's going to install the dependency 'hidapi'. And this is the message, which gives to me

```
`Configuring hidapi-0.1.3...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: udev
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
Failed to install hidapi-0.1.3
```

then I run the command `sudo apt-get install udev` to install `udev` package, but the problem didn't solved!

Comment: The `udev` library is a critical component of Ubuntu. What's missing are the development headers. Try running `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` next.

Comment: I just resposted my comment as an answer for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `udev` library is a critical component of Ubuntu. What's missing are the development headers. Try running `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` first and then installing `hemokit`.